# Version of recycler view and firebase UI dependencies to be added to the following gradle file

Tags: android

I have tried different versions of Firebase UI and RecyclerView` dependencies but the problem still persists.

**App level gradle file dependencies:-**

[image]

**Error Message:-**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change dependency version according to compileSdkVersion version define in gradle file and also you drag a mouse on dependency then android studio suggested latest version for that..

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

for recycler view used below ..

```
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
```

Comment: Thank you recyclerview is synced successfully. Could you also let me know the Firebase UI version I should choose

Comment: above code your firebase version is correct. when ever you add any dependency then you drag mouse on that android  studio provide suggestion for updated dependency.